# Is FFTW capable of Type-V through Type-VIII discrete cosine transforms and discrete sine transforms?

Tags: fft, fftw, dct

When computing FFTs of datasets with particular symmetries, one can often achieve savings in space and time by exploiting the symmetries (giving a reduction roughly proportional to the order of the symmetry group of the data). The existence of these symmetries is why DCTs, DSTs, and realFFT's were invented.

Type-I through Type-IV DCTs and DSTs are built-in to FFTW through the `FFTW.REDFTXY` and `FFTW.RODFTXY` functions (where `X` and `Y` are either `0` or `1`).

However, I don't see any mention of the Type-V through Type-VIII DCTs and DSTs in the documentation. Is there a way to do these in FFTW?

Comment: According to the doc of [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Real-even_002fodd-DFTs-_0028cosine_002fsine-transforms_0029.html) , `There are also type V-VIII transforms, which correspond to a logical DFT of odd size N, independent of whether the physical size n is odd, but we do not support these variants.` I guess that you will have to unfold your signal and get back to the I-IV DCTs/DSTs.